# Issue with using random.choice() with networkx

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking

So, I am getting error with this python script, I am new to python and maybe making a silly mistake, please help me out.

```
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import random
    
    G=nx.Graph()
    city_set=['Ranchi','Delhi','Mumbai','Kolkata','Jaipur','Pune','Surat','Chennai']
    
    for each in city_set:
        G.add_node(each)
    
    # nx.draw(G,with_labels=1)
    # plt.show()
    #print(G.nodes())
    
    # name=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
    # print(name)
    
                                    # Adding edges
        
    costs=[]
    value=100
    
    while(value<2000):
        costs.append(value)
        value+=100
        
    
    while(G.number_of_edges()<16):
        c1=random.choice(G.nodes())
        c2=random.choice(G.nodes())
        
        if (c1!=c2)and (G.has_edge(c1,c2))==0:
            w=random.choice(costs)
            G.add_edge(c1,c2,weight=w)
            
            
    nx.draw(G,with_labels=1)
    plt.show()
```

The error that I am getting is :-

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-67a2861315c5> in <module>
     13 print(G.nodes())
     14 
---> 15 name=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
     16 print(name)
     17 

D:\ANACONDA\lib\random.py in choice(self, seq)
    260         except ValueError:
    261             raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
--> 262         return seq[i]
    263 
    264     def shuffle(self, x, random=None):

D:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py in __getitem__(self, n)
    275 
    276     def __getitem__(self, n):
--> 277         ddict = self._nodes[n]
    278         data = self._data
    279         if data is False or data is True:

KeyError: 2
```

Comment: `G.nodes()` is probably a dictionary

Comment: Yeah I tried typecasting as well something like 

    c1=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
    c2=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
still the error was there

Comment: problem is what do you want to pick? keys or values?,with a list it should work, and it cannot throw keyerror since list does not do that

Comment: Can you give exactly the code you run and the full error?  The code you provide could not have given that error message (the line giving the error is commented out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`G.nodes()` returns a NodeView object which is a dictionary type containing data for each node. As stated in the documentation:
"If your node data is not needed, it is simpler and equivalent to use the expression for n in G, or list(G)."

Use casting to a list on G.nodes():
Fixed:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

G=nx.Graph()
city_set=['Ranchi','Delhi','Mumbai','Kolkata','Jaipur','Pune','Surat','Chennai']

for each in city_set:
    G.add_node(each)

# nx.draw(G,with_labels=1)
# plt.show()
#print(G.nodes())

# name=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
# print(name)

                                # Adding edges

costs=[]
value=100

while(value<2000):
    costs.append(value)
    value+=100


while(G.number_of_edges()<16):
    c1=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
    c2=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))

    if (c1!=c2)and (G.has_edge(c1,c2))==0:
        w=random.choice(costs)
        G.add_edge(c1,c2,weight=w)


nx.draw(G,with_labels=1)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This works on my Anaconda environment with Python 3.8.5. What type of error do you get?

Comment: I copied pasted exactly the same code that you shared, and it showed error 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3ba86db5df7e> in <module>
     27 
     28 while(G.number_of_edges()<16):
---> 29     c1=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
     30     c2=random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
     31

Do you think it has to do anything with me using python 3.8.1 ?

Comment: Full Traceback would be of more help. Anyway, I suspect that your environment is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

`G.nodes()` returns a `NodeView` and when the random function tries to pick an element by its index it fails, since it does not find it.
A solution may consist in using `list(G.nodes())` in your code.
A better option consists in picking directly 2 elements by using [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) instead of picking one at a time and then checking if they are the same.

```
G.add_nodes_from(city_set)
costs = list(range(100,2000,100))

while(G.number_of_edges() < 16):
    c1, c2 = random.sample(city_set, 2)
    if not G.has_edge(c1, c2):
       w = random.choice(costs)
       G.add_edge(c1, c2, weight=w)
```